# Snowflake - how to do multiple DML operations on same primary key in a specific order?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up continuous data replication in Snowflake. I get the transactions happened in source system and I need to perform them in Snowflake in the same order as source system. I am trying to use MERGE for this, but when there are multiple operations on same key in source system, MERGE is not working correctly. It either misses an operation or returns duplicate row detected during DML operation error.

Please note that the transactions need to happen in exact order and it is not possible to take the latest transaction for a key and just do it (like if a record has been INSERTED and UPDATED, in Snowflake too it needs to be inserted first and then updated even though insert is only transient state) .

Here is the example:

```
create or replace table employee_source (
id int,
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255),
operation_name varchar(255),
binlogkey integer
)

create or replace table employee_destination ( id int, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255) );

insert into employee_source values (1,'Wayne','Bells','INSERT',11);
insert into employee_source values (1,'Wayne','BellsT','UPDATE',12);
insert into employee_source values (2,'Anthony','Allen','INSERT',13);
insert into employee_source values (3,'Eric','Henderson','INSERT',14);
insert into employee_source values (4,'Jimmy','Smith','INSERT',15);
insert into employee_source values (1,'Wayne','Bellsa','UPDATE',16);
insert into employee_source values (1,'Wayner','Bellsat','UPDATE',17);
insert into employee_source values (2,'Anthony','Allen','DELETE',18); 

MERGE into employee_destination as T using (select * from employee_source order by binlogkey) 
AS S
ON T.id = s.id
when not matched
And S.operation_name = 'INSERT' THEN
INSERT (id,
first_name,
last_name)
VALUES (
S.id,    
S.first_name,
S.last_name)
when matched AND S.operation_name = 'UPDATE'
THEN
update set T.first_name = S.first_name, T.last_name = S.last_name
When matched
And S.operation_name = 'DELETE' THEN DELETE;
```

I am expecting to see - Bellsat - as last name for employee id 1 in the employee_destination table after all rows get processed. Same way, I should not see emp id 2 in the employee_destination table.

Is there any other alternative to MERGE to achieve this? Basically to go over every single DML in the same order (using binlogkey column for ordering) .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate your source data to ensure that you only have one record per key/operation otherwise the join will be non-deterministic and will (dpending on your settings) either error or will update using a random one of the applicable source records. This is covered in the documentation here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior.

In any case, why would you want to update a record only for it to be overwritten by another update - this would be incredibly inefficient?

Comment: In case of multiple updates, what you said makes sense. But assume the scenario where there is an INSERT and UPDATE, it wouldn't be possible to UPDATE  record without actually having it inserted right? So I am not sure if it would be possible to bring just one record per key. In case of both INSERT and UPDATE being present for same key, MERGE is just doing an INSERT and doesn't do an UPDATE that is meant for same key.

Comment: I don’t think that INSERT/UPDATE scenario changes anything. You still need to get the latest version of each record into your source table and then the MERGE will insert or update depending on whether the key exists in the target

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I am following this. If I get the latest version of each record, then the INSERT transaction for employee id 1 would never happen because we skipped it. Employee 1 would never get inserted in to the target table. How will the subsequent UPDATEs to a key work when there is no record in the target table in first place?

Comment: even with multiple updates, picking up latest transaction is not going to work. there could be a scenario where first UPDATE would have happened for first_name and second UPDATE would have happened for last_name. If we pick latest transaction, only last name would be updated and updates to first name would be skipped. I am editing the post to reflect this.. Changed the first_name for emp id 1 for the latest transaction.

Comment: As long as each record has all fields populated then you can just take the last one for each id and allow the merge statement to determine if it is an insert or update

Comment: I tried taking last record for each id and did merge. It did not work as expected. Emp id 1 was not found in the target table because while taking the latest row, only UPDATE record for emp id 1 picked and INSERT record got skipped. So emp id did not get inserted in to target table in first place, and the UPDATE had no effect because it didn't find a matching key to perform update.

Comment: Have you still got references to the operation_name column in your match clauses? If so you need to remove them from the insert and update logic and make sure the update is after the delete in the matched section

Comment: MERGE into employee_destination as T
using (select *
from employee_source qualify row_number() over (partition by ID order by binlogkey desc) = 1) AS S
ON T.id = s.id
when not matched THEN
INSERT (id,
first_name,
last_name)
VALUES (S.id,
S.first_name,
S.last_name)
When matched And S.operation_name = 'DELETE' THEN DELETE
when matched THEN
update set T.first_name = S.first_name, T.last_name = S.last_name 
;    okay, I tried the above and it ends up inserting all 4 rows in to target table. Emp id 2 should not be present in target because it's last state was DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Since your updates appear to include the new values for all rows, you can use a window function to get to just the latest incoming change, and then merge those results into the target table. For example, the select for that merge (with the window function to get only the latest change) would look like this:

```
with SOURCE_DATA as
(
select   COLUMN1::int       ID
        ,COLUMN2::string    FIRST_NAME
        ,COLUMN3::string    LAST_NAME
        ,COLUMN4::string    OPERATION_NAME
        ,COLUMN5::int       PROCESSING_ORDER
from values 
(1,'Wayne','Bells','INSERT',11),
(1,'Wayne','BellsT','UPDATE',12),
(2,'Anthony','Allen','INSERT',13),
(3,'Eric','Henderson','INSERT',14),
(4,'Jimmy','Smith','INSERT',15),
(1,'Wayne','Bellsa','UPDATE',16),
(1,'Wayne','Bellsat','UPDATE',17),
(2,'Anthony','Allen','DELETE',18)
)
select * from SOURCE_DATA
qualify row_number() over (partition by ID order by PROCESSING_ORDER desc) = 1
```

That will produce a result set that has only the changes required to merge into the target table:

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | OPERATION_NAME | PROCESSING_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wayne | Bellsat | UPDATE | 17 |
| 2 | Anthony | Allen | DELETE | 18 |
| 3 | Eric | Henderson | INSERT | 14 |
| 4 | Jimmy | Smith | INSERT | 15 |

You can then change the `when not matched` to remove the operation_name. If it's listed as an update and it's not in the target table, it's because it was inserted in a previous operation in the new changes.

For the `when matched` clause, you can use the operation_name to determine if the row should be updated or deleted.

Comment: sorry, I didn't follow the last part on 'when not matched'/'when matched'.  If I pick latest transaction for each key using window function, then employee 1 would not have a record in the target table because it was never INSERTED in first place, so the UPDATE transaction wouldn't do anything to it. will this behavior change if when matched/when not match is removed?

Comment: when I run this for first time when the target table is empty, removing operation name from when not matched inserts all 4 rows in to target table. subsequent checks for UPDATE or DELETE doesn't do anything because MERGE handled all 4 rows in the first condition of when not matched itself.  ID 2 should not be present in the target table because its final state was delete.